# Array of planes with different static textures

Tags: texturing, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm designing and rendering a deck of cards. Right now, I have a fan that looks like this:
[image: Fan]

So my main goal is to do the same thing, but have it show the individual faces of the cards. I have tried using the "Generated" option under the texture mapping options on a single image with all the textures side by side. I tweaked the offset and size to make it fit perfectly, but it only works if the X offset of the array is equal to 1:
[image]

If you change it, it looks like this:[image]

So to summarize, I want to have each card have a separate texture that does not change depending on position/offset/rotation/etc, while still maintaining the functionality of the Array modifier. How can I do this?

(By the way, I am using the internal renderer)

Comment: What functionality of the Array modifier do you need to preserve?

Comment: Offsets basically, I want to be able to animate it. I only use an object offset though for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some luck with this approach.

- UV map an array of card geometry against whatever batch-of-cards image you are using. (I imported the image as a plane for reference, adjusted a card-array so the geometry captured the individual cards, and projected the UV from an orthogonal view)
- Apply the array, and <kbd>P</kbd> separate the card-array-object by loose parts. You should now have a set of separate card-objects, each with its own UV coordinate reference to the batch image. (So now, they will use the 'UV' texture space in their common front-face material)
- With all the card-objects selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> set their origins to their geometry.
- Make a Group of the cards
- Make an array of small square Planes, Object-Offset as you choose
- Use the plane-array as an emitter for a particle system, with the card-group as source of instances: the settings something like as shown.. (all other settings null, no physics, velocity, etc.)

[image]

This isn't without minor gotchas.. sometimes the rotations can flip out (gimbal lock?) so watch out for that before committing to a major render.

Hopefully you will retain all the features of array manipulation on the array of plane emitters, and the individual cards will follow. If you 'Use Count' in the particle Render settings, you can select and order the cards in the array.

It's sensible to parent the plane-array and the offset-object to anther empty, so you can transform the whole arrangement with it, without upsetting the array's offset.

Comment: I've gotten this to work, but as you mentioned, the rotations flip out and it's sort of common and extremely noticeable when fanning a full deck. Also, I cannot see any of the object materials for some reason. Do you know of any way to achieve the same type of fan effect without this method?

Comment: @Farex  Hmm.. shame.. the materials surprise me, though, nothing wrong with my version. I'll try to think of another way, that doesn't involve a lot of tedious rigging/set-up. (Or a scripted set-up.. someone might help with that)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly I did but I was in edit mode for a bit and then left it and it suddenly snapped into place and is working perfectly now. I really hope I can replicate it again though. Also I realized the materials was just really crappy lighting and I also didn't set the specular at all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Farex Glad it works.. I'll keep thinking, though, just in case you come  back with : 'Nope, it's just too unstable'