# Arrays: Different image texture

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, image

I've been looking around a little but could not find a definitive answer for this:
Can I setup my nodes in a way that allows for randomly selecting one out of multiple image textures **using an array**?

I am modeling a race track and would like to randomly choose different ads for the hoardings.

Comment: You can set the Pass Index in Object Properties -> Relations to a different number for each Mesh and then use the Object Info -> Object Index node and then use a collection Mix Shaders using the that as the Factor. This will end up a big mess the more Image Textures you want to include. The Object Index can be Math->Multiplied with Object Info -> Random to get more randomness. Python for setting the Pass Index https://blenderartists.org/t/object-index-not-working/637448/4

Comment: Even better example using random Pass Index http://blog.gregzaal.com/2013/07/28/cif-3-object-index/

Comment: Thanks! Have to look into this, looks very interesting..

Comment: You can use an array as a particle emitter, as shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134537/35559), which lets you treat a particle system as if it was an array (of the emitting objects) The your 'array' could all be different shapes and sizes, if you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, great idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant set a different texture for array's duplicates.

However, you can shift their UVs:

[image: demo pic]

As you can see here, I have a texture of 1/3 ratio. Each third has a different pattern.
My array is set to make three different duplicates, and to shift their UVs of a third (1/3= 0,333...) on the V axis.

The result is quite usable.
All you have to do is a texture file containing your different textures aligned on one axis, adapt your UV to one area of the picture, and set your array's number of duplicates and U/V offset accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about what others had done with the **Pass Index** and then threw it all out the window and tried with plain **Random**.

***Cleaner version of Nodes further down.***

I created it as **Node Group** so I could experiment. Here there are 5 different **Image Texture** nodes connected to **Diffuse BSDF Shaders** and each **Shader** is attached to a **Mix Shader**.
[image: Random image Node group]

The **Random** value coming in has a value between 0.0 - 1.0. The framed logic picks out five ranges and uses them to determine the Image Texture shown (0.0 - 0.2 is explicit).

The **Mix Shaders** are controlled by Boolean logic. The **Greater Than** and **Less Than Math Nodes** output 1 for True and 0 for False. The **Minimum Math Nodes** act as ***And gate*** and only let 1 through when both inputs are 1.

Outside the **Node Group** I am simply pumping in the **Object -> Random**
[image: Material using Random image Node group]
And the Result.
[image: result of 5 random images]

It is a bit over the top and to extend it will require tweaking the values to match the number of images required.

***Cleaner version of Nodes.***

And an even cleaner way or structuring those Nodes, reducing unnecessary Nodes. Uses Colours, but an Shader can be used.
[image: Node structure]

Truth table
[image: Truth table]

Small blog post I did on it.
[random blender textures through the magic of logic gates](http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Mar2019.html#p240320191458)

Comment: Awesome, thank you!